# What are the Type.GetType search rules for a type name prefixed with "."?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.0, f#

e.g. `Type.GetType(".System.Collections.ArrayList", false, false)` vs. `Type.GetType("System.Collections.ArrayList", false, false)`

I had presumed that these were equivalent, but I've noticed the former takes twice as long as the latter to resolve and upon further investigation I cannot find explicit support for the former: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx.

Are these equivalent, and if so, any idea why the former twice as long as the latter to resolve?

Comment: Why does it make sense to start the type name with . ?

Comment: @HansPassant - in my mind, starting with `.` was saying "look in the 'global' namespace"... from a practical perspective, if you have a list of "open" namespace you'd like to try resolving a possibly not fully qualified type name against, it is easier to work with a list like `[""; "System"; "System.Collections"]` where `""` represents this imaginary "global" namespace so that you can try all combinations joining the namespace list with the possible type name using the `.` separator without special casing the type name being possibly fully qualified

Comment: Looking at the [grammar for type names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6.aspx), it seems like a bug that the leading period is allowed.

Comment: @StephenSwensen: In the absence of a global namespace specifier, can you fully-qualify using the assembly name instead?

Comment: @Daniel - I'm tending to agree that allowing the leading period must be a bug (the BNF is a good supporting source). I've noticed other indicators that something strange is going on: calling `Type.GetType("..",true,true)` will result in the exception message "Could not load type '.'"... somewhere it is stripping a single leading '.' and forgetting it ever did it.

Comment: @Daniel - the full assembly qualified name doesn't help here, because the syntax has the assembly name following the type name... but not having a global namespace identifier is not really a big deal, I just have to use a function like `let withNamespace tyName ns = if ns = "" then tyName else ns + "." + tyName` to join namespaces (including my conceptual global namespace represented by an empty string) with type names.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you supplied:

> Period (`.`) Denotes namespace identifiers.

I would *guess* having the leading `.` causes ALL namespaces to be scanned, even ones outside the current assembly.

Comment: I had a similar thought, yet `Type.GetType(".Collections.ArrayList", false, false)` does not resolve

Answer (score 0):

There is really no concept of global namespace here, because namespaces that you have open doesn't matter in this context.

Think of it as always searching from the root (global). Type.GetType is not 'in' any namespace and does not have any namespaces open. You have to qualify the type you're searching for, including its namespace.